# Proving the Completeness of a Metric Space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, complete-spaces

Let $C[0,1]$ represent the set of all continuous functions on $[0,1]$. Is the following subset of $C[0,1]$ complete with respect to the metric $\rho(f,g) = \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$?

The subset in question is $$X = \{f \in C[0,1] |  f(x) > 1 \forall x \in [0,1]\}$$

I understand that to prove this we need to show that every Cauchy sequence converges to a limit in the metric space, but I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: You only need to check if it closed since every closed subset of a complete metric space is also complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not complete, since it is not closed. And it is not clolsed because, if you define $f_n\in C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ by $f_n(x)=1+\frac1n$, then $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ converges in $C\bigl([0,1]\bigr)$ to the constant function $1$, which doesn't belong to $X$. However, each $f_n$ belongs to $X$.

Comment: Beat me to it. For OP: strict inequalities do not really play well with completeness. This is a very classic example where it doesn't.

Comment: I suppose what I am confused about is the set-up of the metric $sup|f(x)-g(x)|$. What if I wanted to prove that the subset of continuous functions on [0,1] where $\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx=1$ is complete with respect to the metric?

Comment: @roc11111111 That set is complete because it is closed. And it is closed because the function $f\mapsto\int_0^1f(x)\,\mathrm dx$ is continuous with respect to your metric and because $\{1\}$ is a closed set.